# Dynamic reloading of CamelContext with SpringXML

Tags: apache-camel

Is it a good practice to load the entire Camel context from SpringXML (rather than dynamic re-loading of routes). Following code snippet seems to load the updated camel context from the file systems (based on a FileWatch service). Is that recommended?

```
// Detect file modification... 

camelContext.stop();
camelContext.destroy();
((AbstractApplicationContext)applicationContext).close();

SpringCamelContext.setNoStart(true);
applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
   new String[]{CAMEL_CONTEXT_FILE});
camelContext = (SpringCamelContext) applicationContext.getBean("foo-cc");
camelContext.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like something that might be OK during development. This way it is possible to reload more than just routes, as Spring beans and configuration will be reloaded. Now, whether it is recommended or not would depend on what you're trying to accomplish and in what environment.

Comment: Yes, I think we wouldn't do that in a production environment. So for development, I guess it should be ok to use that. May be its more practical to load the routes dynamically(http://camel.apache.org/loading-routes-from-xml-files.html) than the entire context in a prod and dev environments.